# How to determine 24h trading volume of a trading pair/pool / fetch large number of transactions?

Tags: web3.js, transactions, getsignaturesforaddress

I would like to determine the (24h) trading volume of tokens or pools/pairs, as displayed by Dextools or Dexscreener, for example.

I had followed the following approach:

- get all signatures of the last 24 hours for the pair address
- use the signatures to obtain the corresponding transactions
- filter transactions by swaps or something (I have not yet implemented this step)

the reason why i have not yet implemented the last step is that it takes several minutes to retrieve the tens of thousands of transactions. i wonder if there is a faster way to determine the trading volume for a certain period of time.

this is my code:

```
const [recentPerformanceSample] =
  await connection.getRecentPerformanceSamples(1);

const slotTimeInSeconds =
  recentPerformanceSample.samplePeriodSecs /
  recentPerformanceSample.numSlots;

const currentSlot = await connection.getSlot();
const slot24hAgo = Math.round(currentSlot - 86400 / slotTimeInSeconds); // 86400 seconds = 24 hours

const allSignatures = [];
const signatures = await connection.getSignaturesForAddress(
  new PublicKey(pairAddress)
);
allSignatures.push(...signatures);

while (allSignatures[allSignatures.length - 1].slot > slot24hAgo) {
  const moreSignatures = await connection.getSignaturesForAddress(
    new PublicKey(pairAddress),
    { before: allSignatures[allSignatures.length - 1].signature }
  );
  allSignatures.push(...moreSignatures);
}

const allSignaturesFilteredBySlot = allSignatures
  .filter(
    (signature: ConfirmedSignatureInfo) => signature.slot >= slot24hAgo
  )
  .map((signature: ConfirmedSignatureInfo) => signature.signature);

const allDetailedTransactions = [];

const chunks = chunkArray(allSignaturesFilteredBySlot, 1000);

for (const chunk of chunks) {
  const detailedTransactions = await connection.getParsedTransactions(
    chunk,
    { maxSupportedTransactionVersion: 0 }
  );
  allDetailedTransactions.push(...detailedTransactions);
}
```

There must be an easier way to determine the trading volume. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Hey there! If you don't mind me asking, is there a reason why you want to implement this yourself, as opposed to just querying the `dexscreener` endpoint?

Comment: Hi Ademola, thank you for your question.
I would not like to be dependent on such an endpoint and I would be very interested to know how this can be implemented. But thank you for pointing out the possibility. With Ethereum I have no problem determining the trading volume myself, but with solana there are simply too many signatures that occur in the 24h period for me to be able to process them quickly.

Comment: It for sure looks like you're on the right path so far with your approach; however, it remains a difficult task to beat the latency limits. You should consider relying on a dedicated rpc indexing solution for (potentially) faster retrieval of the 24h tx data?